# Unknown string format on pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, datetime

I have a data set with a column date like this:

```
cod           date              value 
0   1O8        2015-01-01 00:00:00    2.1
1   1O8        2015-01-01 01:00:00    2.3
2   1O8        2015-01-01 02:00:00    3.5
3   1O8        2015-01-01 03:00:00    4.5
4   1O8        2015-01-01 04:00:00    4.4
5   1O8        2015-01-01 05:00:00    3.2
6   1O9        2015-01-01 00:00:00    1.4
7   1O9        2015-01-01 01:00:00    8.6
8   1O9        2015-01-01 02:00:00    3.3
10  1O9        2015-01-01 03:00:00    1.5
11  1O9        2015-01-01 04:00:00    2.4
12  1O9        2015-01-01 05:00:00    7.2
```

The `dtypes` of column date is an object, for apply some function after I need to change the date column type to datatime. I try a diffrent solution like:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='raise', format ='%Y-%m-%d HH:mm:ss')
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', format ='%Y-%m-%d HH:mm:ss')
df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format ='%Y-%m-%d HH:mm:ss')
```

But the error is only the same:

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

The straight thing is that if I apply te function to a sample of data set, the function respond correctly, but if I apply it to all data set exit the error. In the data there isn missing value and the dtype is the same for all value.

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried without specifying any format, i.e `pd.to_datetime(df.date)`?

Comment: Yes, is the first thing that I tryed

Comment: Because it usually infers the format. And as @jpp mentions, you're missing `%`at the beginning of the string formats.

Answer (score 18):

There are three issues:

1. `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.Series.apply` don't work in place, so your solutions won't modify your series. Assign back after conversion.
2. Your third solution needs `errors='coerce'` to guarantee no errors.
3. For the time component you need to use specific string formats beginning with `%`.

So you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-12-20 15:00:20',
                            '2017-08-05 00:05:00', '2018-05-11 00:10:00']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(df)

                  date
0  2015-01-01 00:00:00
1  2016-12-20 15:00:20
2  2017-08-05 00:05:00
3  2018-05-11 00:10:00
```

In this particular instance, the format is standard and can be omitted:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I tryed to use this type of format: `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' ` but the error now is : `ValueError: time data 'dVal' doesn't match format specified`. Theorically the format is correct

Comment: @jjgasse, Your inputs don't align with your format, see my example, there's no `.%f`. And looks like you *still* aren't using `errors='coerce'`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you read this data for example from csv file.

```
df=pd.read_csv('c:/1/comptagevelo2012.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

To check:

```
print(df.index)
```

Is works better than pd.to_datetime!! I checked it!

```
> DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', '2012-03-01', '2012-04-01',
>                '2012-05-01', '2012-06-01', '2012-07-01', '2012-08-01',
>                '2012-09-01', '2012-10-01',
>                ...
>                '2012-12-22', '2012-12-23', '2012-12-24', '2012-12-25',
>                '2012-12-26', '2012-12-27', '2012-12-28', '2012-12-29',
>                '2012-12-30', '2012-12-31'],
>               dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=366, freq=None)
```

Another method doesn't work for this file.

```
df=pd.read_csv('c:/1/comptagevelo2012.csv',index_col=0)
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],  errors='coerce', format ='%d/%m/%Y')
print(df.index)

Index(['01/01/2012', '02/01/2012', '03/01/2012', '04/01/2012', '05/01/2012',
       '06/01/2012', '07/01/2012', '08/01/2012', '09/01/2012', '10/01/2012',
       ...
       '22/12/2012', '23/12/2012', '24/12/2012', '25/12/2012', '26/12/2012',
       '27/12/2012', '28/12/2012', '29/12/2012', '30/12/2012', '31/12/2012'],
      dtype='object', length=366)
```

sorce: https://keyrus-gitlab.ml/gfeuillen/keyrus-training/blob/5f0076e3c61ad64336efc9bc3fd862bfed53125c/docker/data/python/Exercises/02%20pandas/comptagevelo2012.csv