# I'm trying to calculate time difference, but facing the following error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image: Starting and end times]

I need to calculate the time difference in minutes and create a separate entry in the data frame in minutes

I tried and got the following error

[image: 2nd try]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. After that please update your question that it can help other readers, too.

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
start_time = pd.to_datetime(df['Start time'].astype(str)) 
end_time = pd.to_datetime(df['End time'].astype(str))
df['diff'] = end_time.sub(start_time).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
```

I have stored values in seperate variable `start_time and end_time` to do not override dataframe (i.e. Without convering datatype of columns to `datetime`). Otherwise you can directly use it without saving in variables.

Comment: You can remove `.astype(str)` and chain methods without to store intermediate variables.

Comment: start_time = pd.to_datetime(n2['Start time'].astype(str)) 
end_time = pd.to_datetime(n2['End time'].astype(str))

n2['diff'] = end_time.sub(start_time).dt.total_seconds().div(60)

Comment: @MaruthiRamMNV, Sorry i didnt get your point

Comment: Parser error: Unknown string format: twill

Comment: @MaruthiRamMNV, It is better to have your code as well to understand where did you got this error, or please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537443/unknown-string-format-on-pd-to-datetime

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime`:

[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start time': ['07:15:00'], 'End time': ['10:40:00']})
```

```
df['Diff time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End time']) \
                        .sub(pd.to_datetime(df['Start time'])) \
                        .dt.total_seconds().div(60)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Start time  End time  Diff time
0   07:15:00  10:40:00      205.0
```